# Laravel export to excel file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

What's the best library for laravel to use when it comes to exporting data to an excel file ? something that uses a template would be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Laravel Excel](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/3.0/getting-started/installation) if you need to add dropdown in your excel sheet [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io) would a good choice over [Laravel Excel](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/3.0/getting-started/installation)

For Laravel Excel you can simply

```
Excel::loadView('folder.file', $data)
->setTitle('FileName')
->sheet('SheetName')
->mergeCells('A2:B2')
->export('xls');
```

Comment: Would I be able to use a template ? Because my data contains headers that require merged cells. So, maybe I'm thinking of something that uses a library, or something that can manually merge cells

Comment: Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::loadView()

Already added service providers and aliases

Comment: depends on what you have set in your config, please read https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/2.1/blade/load-view#docs

Comment: What's the purpose of the view btw ? Is it something like, the $data variable will be loaded in the folder.file view, then the output will be the same with the exported excel file ?

Comment: if you want to use template,  for reports etc... you can make the view, and pass the data to that view

Comment: I see. I understand, but first I have to fix this undefined method . even ::create cant be found.

Comment: https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/3.0/getting-started/installation please check if you followed all steps for installation

Comment: Yes I did follow the instructions, until the vendor:publish

Answer (score 0):

Use maatwebsite to Create and import Excel, CSV and PDF files

Add this lines to your composer.json:

```
"require": {
   "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"
}
```

After updating composer, add the ServiceProvider to the providers array in config/app.php

```
Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
```

You can use the facade for shorter code. Add this to your aliasses:

```
'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
```

To publish the config settings in Laravel 5 use:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider"
```